How to set random seeds globally?
I have observed that when I set the random seed using np.random.seed(seed) and then generate random numbers in a loop, as shown below:
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(4)
for i in range(3):
    print(np.random.uniform(0, 1, 4))

I get three different lists of random numbers. However, if I set the random seed within the loop, I obtain the same list of random numbers each time.
Is there a way to globally set the random seed such that it remains consistent even within loops? I want it so that any randomly generated points are generated according to the global seed.

Then it is not random at all? What are the result you were expecting from your sample code? 3 times the same size-4 array of numbers?

When you set the seed in the loop you are starting the random function with that seed; when the seed is set before the loop the random function starts with that seed and continues through all the looping. You have to reset the seed whenever you want to restart the sequence - that's what the seed is for.

All points are generated to the seed. The seed advances each time you generate a sequence. You want the seed to be reset each call?

No, there is no way. The random number generator doesn't know when it's being called from a loop. It just generates a (hopefully) long sequence of pseudo-random numbers, and the sequence is deterministically initialized as a function of a seed. Whenever you want the restart the same sequence you need to reseed with the same seed.

This sounds like an XY problem. What did you really want to achieve by fixing the seed?

Supplemental to all the other feedback comments posted, as it seems you are unclear as to the behaviour of the function I recommend reading the documentation on how things behave as a method of gaining understanding. https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html

@KamilCuk Not quite. The generator’s internal state is advanced each time you call the generator. The initial state is a function of the seed, but it is not the seed. Similarly, the output of the generator is a function of the state, but it is not the state. See this post from several years back. That’s why OP gets the behavior noted in their question, and why President James K. Polk’s response is correct.
